# More Node Access Product (nap.module) Problems

Tags: ubercart, users

I have a client who cannot launch his website because of continuing problems with the [Node access product](http://drupal.org/project/nap) module.

After a customer makes a purchase, they are prompted to login. Upon attempting to login they receive a white screen with the following message -

> "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/nap/nap.module on line 824"

Have already looked everywhere for a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$purchases['product_vid']` to `$purchases->product_vid` on line 824. [Issue](http://drupal.org/node/1955892) has been created on the project.

Comment: It worked! thanks Triskelion. I have some other problems now but I'll just post it as a new question.